# Remap ports on internal network in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, network-programming, portforwarding

I'm using docker-compose to start services `foo` and `bar` which both run apps that bind to port `8080`.

Is it possible to remap these ports on the internal docker network as `foo:80` and `bar:80`?

I obviously don't want them exposed to `host:80`.

Comment: When you make connections between containers, it always uses the port the service inside the container listens on; you cannot remap the ports.  Compose `ports:` aren't required and aren't used if present.  You'd connect to `foo:8080` or `bar:8080`.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes this further.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I now use `socat` as a port forwarder. It's obviously not suited for production environment, but for local development it seems sufficient:

```
nohup sudo /usr/bin/socat -d tcp4-listen:80,fork,reuseaddr tcp4:127.0.0.1:8080 </dev/null >socat.log 2>&1 &
```